# Problem with finding the GCD for the elements of a list using max and lambda

Tags: python, lambda, max

So this is my code, and i've used a lambda function as a key to find the max of the result list, but it wont work. I don't want to use any other built in functions or methods, just modify the KEY if possible. The result for this given list should be 6, but my code returns 1!

```
def find_gcd(my_list):
    result = []
    for item in my_list:
        for divs in range(1, item+1):
            if item % divs ==0:
                result.append(divs)

    result.sort()

    x = max(result, key = lambda x : result.count(x))
    return x
print(find_gcd([12, 24, 6, 18]))
```

Comment: You code returns number with max occurrences. 1 divides all numbers so it returns 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `key` to this:

```
max(result, key = lambda x : (result.count(x), x))
```

your `result` in your scenario (`find_gcd([12, 24, 6, 18])`) is this:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 9, 12, 12, 18, 24]
```

we have same number of `1`s , `2`s ,`3`s and `6`s in the `result` as you see.(both have 4 occurrence). but we want the **greatest** one.

**NOTE**: We can use two element `tuple` for these problem. the first element for number of occurrence (e.g: 4 occurrence for number 1) and the second one is the number itself. between `(4, 1)` and `(4, 6)`, the `(4, 6)` is greater and it will return.

Comment: so we are passing multiple two-element tuples to the max function to chose the greatest? I understand that (4,6) is the greatest of all the tuples generated by lambda, but why is the second element of (4,6) returned and not the first element also?

Comment: @Sherafati, this is how `key` in `max` and similar functions works. `max` use `key` as a function to find the max element and return element in `result` based on that